# Mysql merge field from table to another

Tags: mysql, merge

I want to merge the field "price" from the table "products" into the field "price" in the table "products_description". Both tables has "products_id" that match.

Can't really get my head around it.

Comment: -1 for question.  I think 'getting head around it' a bit more is a requirement.  Although I know what it's like to not know how to frame up the question -- of course that's when you most need the help!  In any case, the need is not presented clearly.

Comment: How do you suggest I frase it then? Should I show table structure? Should I show example data? English is not my first language so maybe I write in bad language sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:-

```
UPDATE products_description pd
INNER JOIN products p 
ON p.productid = pd.productid
SET 
    pd.price = p.price;
```

That will copy the price from table products into products_description! Although it may not be 100% apparent this is what you want.

Comment: Well. this may do what he wanted, but shows a very bad flaw in the database design. Duplicated data does not even comply with the first NF.

Comment: This depends, why not ask him why he is doing this before citing NF?

It may well be duplicated data or it may not. There could be many reasons for this.

Comment: The reason was that I was moving data from an old database to a new one that have different table design.